# Update existing value in an element, Adding new element in array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am comparing 2 Lists. If both list exists in one of the element, it updates the element values. If it is not found, then it will add into the array. But it seems that it adds every time it loops in even with conditions. It seems like i need to add/update the arrayList only after the 2nd loop ends. Not sure if there are any possibility in doing that

Below are my codes:

```
for(var bscsEntry : bscsChargeTypemap.entrySet()) {
    Report report = new Report();
    for(int i = 0; i < reportDataList.size(); i++) {
        if(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(reportDataList.get(i).getChargeTypeName())) {
            reportDataList.get(i).setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getAmount());
            reportDataList.get(i).setBscsQuantity(bscsEntry.getValue().getQuantity());
        }else {
            report.setChargeTypeName(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName());
            report.setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getAmount());
            report.setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getQuantity());
            reportDataList.add(report);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the lists:

Existing Report Data List

```
Type : [Name : TypeA, Amount : 10.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeB, Amount : 5.0 , Quantity : 2]
Type : [Name : TypeC, Amount : 55.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeD, Amount : 10.0 , Quantity : 2]
```

Map Entry Sets

```
Type : [Name : TypeA, Amount : 10.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeB, Amount : 5.0 , Quantity : 2]
Type : [Name : TypeE, Amount : 65.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeF, Amount : 100.0 , Quantity : 2]
```

Expected outcome of existing Report Data List

```
Type : [Name : TypeA, Amount : 20.0 , Quantity : 2]
Type : [Name : TypeB, Amount : 10.0 , Quantity : 4]
Type : [Name : TypeC, Amount : 55.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeD, Amount : 10.0 , Quantity : 2]
Type : [Name : TypeE, Amount : 65.0 , Quantity : 1]
Type : [Name : TypeF, Amount : 100.0 , Quantity : 2]
```

Updated POJO:

```
public class ChargeType {

    private String chargeTypeName;
    private Double amount;
    private Integer quantity;
    
    public ChargeType() {
        chargeTypeName = "";
        amount = Double.parseDouble("0");
        quantity = 0;
    }
    
    public ChargeType(String chargeTypeName, Double amount, Integer quantity) {
        this.chargeTypeName = chargeTypeName;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getChargeTypeName() {
        return chargeTypeName;
    }

    public void setChargeTypeName(String chargeTypeName) {
        this.chargeTypeName = chargeTypeName;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}



public class Report {
    private String chargeTypeName;
    private Double brmAmount;
    private Integer brmQuantity;
    private Double bscsAmount;
    private Integer bscsQuantity;
    private String remarks;
    
    public Report() {
        chargeTypeName = "";
        brmAmount = Double.parseDouble("0");
        brmQuantity = 0;
        bscsAmount = Double.parseDouble("0");
        bscsQuantity = 0;
        remarks = "";
    }

    public String getChargeTypeName() {
        return chargeTypeName;
    }

    public void setChargeTypeName(String chargeTypeName) {
        this.chargeTypeName = chargeTypeName;
    }

    public Double getBrmAmount() {
        return brmAmount;
    }

    public void setBrmAmount(Double brmAmount) {
        this.brmAmount = brmAmount;
    }

    public Integer getBrmQuantity() {
        return brmQuantity;
    }

    public void setBrmQuantity(Integer brmQuantity) {
        this.brmQuantity = brmQuantity;
    }

    public Double getBscsAmount() {
        return bscsAmount;
    }

    public void setBscsAmount(Double bscsAmount) {
        this.bscsAmount = bscsAmount;
    }

    public Integer getBscsQuantity() {
        return bscsQuantity;
    }

    public void setBscsQuantity(Integer bscsQuantity) {
        this.bscsQuantity = bscsQuantity;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You are falling through your conditions since you are checking every element in `reportDataList` against one element of `bscsChargeTypemap`. Which essentially means you are matching 1 element of x elements. The result of the fall through are the extra rows.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz ah yes, thats the issue im facing right now. im having extra records than intended. Are there any ways to do it ?

Comment: You need some kind of a flag mechanism. How does your Pojos look like?

Comment: I have updated my 2 pojos @MuratKaragöz

Comment: How come that you have a map? You could leverage the `contains()`. With that you would not need a loop at all.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz reason for a map is because i need to accumulate values for duplicate chargeType.  if i use `contains()` , i wouldnt be able to get the index for me to update the particular element right ?

Comment: Iterate over your list and check if the map contains it. Otherwise add a new element to the list.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz i have to check the other way round. i have to check if the list contains it

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to create a new list and merge the two lists after iteration, something like this

```
List<Report> additional = new ArrayList<>();
for(var bscsEntry : bscsChargeTypemap.entrySet()) {
    Report report = new Report();
    for(int i = 0; i < reportDataList.size(); i++) {
        if(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase(reportDataList.get(i).getChargeTypeName())) {
            reportDataList.get(i).setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getAmount());
            reportDataList.get(i).setBscsQuantity(bscsEntry.getValue().getQuantity());
        }else {
            report.setChargeTypeName(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName());
            report.setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getAmount());
            report.setBscsAmount(bscsEntry.getValue().getQuantity());
            additional.add(report);
        }
    }
}
reportDataList.addAll(additional);
```

Comment: the problem im facing is it adds multiple times. So lets say if it hits the IF-Condition, it will update the element, but after that, for the next data, it hit the ELSE-statement, and add again. so intead of having 6 records, the list will have like 20++ records.

Comment: what is the key for bscsChargeTypemap

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. This is how I write the logic.
The code to check if it exists in the List:

```
Boolean isExist = reportDataList.stream()
        .anyMatch(i -> i.getChargeTypeName()
        .equalsIgnoreCase(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName()));
```

The code to find index if exists:

```
int dataIndex = IntStream.range(0, reportDataList.size())
                .filter(i -> reportDataList.get(i).getChargeTypeName()
                .equalsIgnoreCase(bscsEntry.getValue().getChargeTypeName()))
                .findFirst().getAsInt();
```

This way, I don't have to make the nested loop. Thank you for the help everyone